# How to access javascript variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
var dat = null;

$.get("example.com", function(data){
    dat = data;
    alert(dat); // Has the info.
});

alert(dat); // null.
```

How can I access `dat` outside `$.get`?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: the `alert(dat)` statement is executed before your `$.get()` method populates `dat`

Comment: Ahh, thank you for pointing this out. To both of you. What should I do with this question now?

Comment: @user1745738 I think you should do what ever you need to do with `data` inside the `$.get()` callback function

Answer (score 2):

Accessing that variable should work fine. The problem is that the function which sets dat will run after the last alert.

The function is a callback.. it only runs after get has complete, whereas the last alert will run straight away.

Here is a way to chain code after the callback

```
var dat = null;

$.get("example.com", function(data){
    dat = data;
    alert(dat); // Has the info.
}).then(function() {
   alert(dat); // Has the info too.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The line alert(data); is executed before the $.get() because the async. Use the $.ajax() with async:false or put alert(data) in success of $.get():

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "example.com",
    success: function(data) {
           dat = data;
           alert(dat);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e); //error
    }
});
```